# How Do I Save the Right Version of My Excel File with Save Lockout Active?

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I think I have my Excel VBA where I want it (checking for cell completion before allowing saving) but that also means I can't save the blank version of that form for distribution.  I'm probably missing something obvious but...I guess, disabling the macros and then reenabling it would work but apparently I can't figure it out.  I've tried googling it but I only get system-wide toggling.

Comment: This is untested, but I *think* it will do what you want: 1) Comment out the before save code 2) Save and close the file 3) Open it with macros disabled 4) Un-comment out the code, 5) save and close the file

Comment: Well, that makes sense...but...when I go to the macros screen in Excel, it says they are disabled.  So...I need to disable them on open for this sheet.  I'm sure there's a way to do that but I couldn't find it by searching.  Also, for whatever reason, when I comment out the save code I get an unlabeled "400" error when running but I've yet to receive that error when the code is uncommented.

Comment: Well, I used the '400' code to my advantage.  I commented out Cancel = True in the appropriate spot, saved with my save button which throws the 400 code.  Then I could save even with the uncommented code (presumably because of the error).  When I closed out everything and reopened, everything is running fine.  Go figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just to put a bow on things.  The correct way to deal with  this is to go through the formal file opening process in Excel.  Assuming you have the proper macro setting in Excel (disable macros with prompt), if you open Excel, Use File Open (DO NOT SELECT RECENT FILES) and browse to the file, select it and open.  Then you should get the standard prompt even if you've enabled it for that file in the past.